# estimate population percentage within an interval, given a small sample

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

Given a small sample from a normally-distributed population, how  do I calculate the confidence that a specified percentage of the population is within some bounds [A,B]?

To make it concrete, if I get a sample of [50,51,52] from a normally-distributed set, I should be able to calculate a fairly high confidence that 50% of the population lies within the range of 0-100, even with such a small sample.

This is certainly related to the "tolerance interval", but differs in an important way. In all of the examples I can find for tolerance intervals, the required percentile and confidence is given, and the interval is found. In my problem, the interval and percentile are given, and I need to find the confidence.

The relevant equation is this one: [(Guttman 1970)](http://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplrp/fplrp458.pdf)

$$1 - \gamma = P\left[P(X \geqq t_0) \geqq 1 - p\right] = P\left[T_{n-1}^*(\sqrt n z_p) \leqq \sqrt n K\right]$$

With definitions:

- $1 - \gamma$ is the confidence
- $n$ is the number of samples
- $100p$ is the percentage of the population required to be within the interval, as estimated from the sample mean and sample variance.
- $t_0 = x - K_{S, z_p}$ is the $(1 - p) 100$th percentile of the standard normal distribution
- $T_v^*(\delta)$ is the noncentral Student’s t distribution with $v$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\delta$.

This solves the one-sided problem, but I'm having trouble extending this to the two-sided problem. In confidence-interval land, I'd use the fact that $P(t_1 \leqq X \leqq t_2) = 1 - P(t_1 \gt X) - P(X \gt t_2)$, to break this into two one-sided problems, but in tolerance-interval land I need to relate these back to the confidence ($1-\gamma$), and I don't see how.

$$1 - \gamma = P\left[P(t_1 \geqq X \geqq t_2) \geqq 1 - p\right] = ??? $$

If I attempt to turn this into two one-sided problems:

$$1 - \gamma = P\left[1 - P(t_1 \lt X) - P(X \lt t_2) \geqq 1 - p\right] = ??? $$

And I'm utterly stuck there. I don't see how to relate this back to the one-sided tolerance interval solution.

---

I'm not certain this is useful for people to understand the question, but it might, so I'm putting it in this addenda.

In scipy, I'm able to pretty easily calculate $K$ given $p$ $\gamma$ and $n$ as:

```
def K(p, gamma, n):
    from scipy import stats
    return stats.nct.ppf(1-gamma, n-1, sqrt(n) * stats.norm.ppf(1-p)) / sqrt(n)
```

I'm also able to find $\gamma$ given $K$ $p$ and $n$ as:

```
def gamma(p, n, K):
    from scipy import stats                                                                                              
    z_p = stats.norm.ppf(1-p)
    return 1 - stats.nct.cdf(sqrt(n) * K, n-1, sqrt(n) * z_p)
```

---

Much less important, but is this a valid simplification of the Guttman's formula?

$$1 - \gamma = P\left[P(X \geqq t_0) \geqq 1 - p\right] = P\left[T_{n-1}^*(\sqrt n z_p) \leqq \sqrt n K\right]$$
$$\gamma = P\left[P(X \geqq t_0) \lt 1 - p\right] = P\left[T_{n-1}^*(\sqrt n z_p) \gt \sqrt n K\right]$$
$$\gamma = P\left[P(X \lt t_0) \lt p\right] = P\left[T_{n-1}^*(\sqrt n z_p) \gt \sqrt n K\right]$$

If so, this form seems way easier to understand, to me.

Comment: Could you rephrase your "concrete question" in more mathematical terms ? Do you want to estimate the probability that the unknown normal distribution falls within a given interval ?

Comment: The probability that any distribution "falls within" a given range will be 1, since all normal distributions have the reals as their domain. I'm trying to estimate the probability that any one sample in the population falls within a specified acceptable range. This is what I try to express by "percentage of the population".

Comment: I try to rephrase my question: do you want to estimate $\Pr(X \in [a,b])$ for a given interval $[a,b]$ ? (this probability is not $1$...)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, I believe so. I take that to mean the probibility that the random variable X will be between a and b. Seem right. Secondarily, I believe I need the confidence of this estimate (I think).

Comment: To estimate this probability you just need to estimate the mean and the standard deviation. There are some frequentist methods to get a confidence interval about $\Pr(X>t)$ or $\Pr(X<t)$. With a Bayesian approach it is very easy to get a confidence about $\Pr(X \in I)$ for any interval $I$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent If it's easy, it should be easy to tell me how to do it (hint hint). :)

Comment: Do you know the basics of Bayesian statistics ? And are you a `R` user ?

Comment: Nope and Nope. I have scipy. Plain english with some pseudocode / simple math expressions would be plenty helpful.

Comment: I'll try to help you when I'll be less busy. But you can also take a look (with the help of Google) at the notion of *tolerance intervals*. I think this is related to your aim.

Comment: I'm under the impression you're on the right way now. You are right: a kind of "inversion" of tolerance intervals provide a confidence interval about a "one-sided" probability $\Pr(X>t)$, but that does'nt work for $\Pr(a \leq X \leq b)$. This problem is straightforward with Bayesian statistics, I hope I'll find the time to write an answer if nobodyelse does it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I also have that hope :) I've added a bounty to sweeten the deal slightly.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: you have a certain number of successes and failures, and you want to guess the percentage of the underlying population. You calculate the Agresti-Coull interval (see Brown, Cai, & DasGupta 2001) with the required parameters.

On the bright side this is easy and makes no assumptions about the type of distribution. On the downside it doesn't take advantage of the extra information about where the samples in the interval fall -- if you know something about how they are distributed this might get you a more precise estimate based on the data you have.

Edit: for a brief overview see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval

Comment: Yes but I think he wants to take the advantage of the Gaussian  distributional assumption.

Comment: I don't believe this will ever accomplish the scenario in my second paragraph: "if I get a sample of [50,51,52] from a normally-distributed set, I should be able to calculate a fairly high confidence that 50% of the population lies within the range of 0-100, even with such a small sample."

Answer (score 1):

The following R code simulates the posterior distribution of the Bayesian Gaussian model $y_i \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ starting with the Jeffreys prior and returns the $100(1-\alpha)\%$ equi-tailed two-sided confidence interval about the probability $\Pr({\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2) \in [a,b])$.

```
# confidence inteval about  Pr(a < N(mu,sigma^2) < b)
bounds <- function(y, a, b, alpha=.05, nsims=10000){
        n <- length(y)
    ssq <- (n-1)*var(y)
    rho <- rchisq(nsims,n)/ssq
    mu <- rnorm(nsims, mean(y), 1/sqrt(n*rho))
    p <- pnorm(b,mu,1/sqrt(rho))-pnorm(a,mu,1/sqrt(rho))
return(quantile(p, c(alpha/2,1-alpha/2)))
}
```

Example:

```
> n <- 100
> y <- rnorm(n,0,1)
> bounds(y,a=-1.96,b=1.96)
     2.5%     97.5% 
0.9146264 0.9773575
```

There's no theoretical guarantee that the confidence level is well controlled (that is, for example, the effective confidence level of the confidence interval with  $95\%$ nominal confidence level is not exactly $95\%$). You should use simulations to check, but I think the effective confidence level is rather close to the nominal one.

Comment: Thanks! Where is a good place to find the definition of those functions? Also I don't quite understand the final output. What exactly are those four numbers?

Comment: I'll come back later (or tomorrow) to provide more details. Actually there's only 2 numbers in the output : $0.9146$ is the lower $2.5\%$-confidence bound and $0.977$ is the upper $97.5\%$-confidence bound, thus $[0.9146,0.977]$ is a two-sided  $95\%$-confidence interval (called *equi-tailed*).

Comment: Could you please define these? `yi` `~` `iid` `ssq` `rho`

Comment: If I understand this solution correctly, you're using simulated random outcomes to avoid integration across the estimated parameters. This adds another layer of uncertainty which doesn't seem entirely necessary. Is there a similar solution which uses integration rather than simulation?

Comment: @bukzor Type something like "conjugate bayesian analysis gaussian distribution" in Google. The posterior distribution of $\sigma^2$ is an inverse-Gamma and the conditional posterior distribution of $\mu$ given $\sigma$ is Gaussian. Thus the joint distribution of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is not complicated but we need the inverse cumulative distribution of the probability, which is quite more complicated.

Comment: @bukzor BTW sorry if my answers are not well appropriate. Actually I'm a little puzzled because I cannot assess your knowledge. You seem to be a little ignorant about statistics, don't you ? How about mathematics in general, and probability theory ?

Comment: I'm a programmer by training and trade. I know probability theory well, but only basic statistics (confidence intervals) and my "general mathematics" are not strong. I've attempted to re-phrase this problem as a programming issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16903259

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using bootstraping. It is especially very useful for small sample size case. You can get more information about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)

Comment: Will bootstrapping be able to accomplish the scenario in my second paragraph? I've looked at bootstrapping before, but all the descriptions were too vague for me to create a concrete implementation. Do you know of any simple implementations I could look at?

Comment: Boostraping is only asymptotically valid (i.e. for large sample sizes).

Comment: @bukzor you can check here: http://photon.isy.liu.se:81/~fredrik/spcourse/Zoubir.pdf  and http://eprints.qut.edu.au/14131/1/14131.pdf   it has many applications including the composite hypothesis testing. It is used primarily when the sample size is small. It is computationally expensive for real time applications. Please have a look at the references. If you are talking about small sample size and lack of samples to build you statistical model, then atually you are talking about bootstrap.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent what do you mean?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Bootstrap is not valid for small sample sizes. For instance the effective coverage of the bootstrap $95\%$-confidence interval is *not* $95\%$, and generally it is really smaller. Mathematical results about bootstrap are asymptotic results ($n \to \infty$). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Disadvantages

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent The **main** reason using bootstrap is the lack of samples. Via resampling you can recover the statistics of your data or your estimator."When I know little about the statistics of the data and/or I have only a few data so that asymptotic theory does not apply", then I use bootstrap. Consistency is **always** defined in asymptotic sense. An estimator is consistent if it approaches to the true parameter in probability when $n\rightarrow \infty$. if bootstrap has this probability then it seem it is something good.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Bootstrap is only asymptotically valid. So your claim *"asymptotic theory does not apply then I use bootstrap"* is wrong. See any textbook about large sample theory. The reason is clear: when $n \to \infty$, the empirical cumulative distribution function goes to the true cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you are not the one who will teach me the large sample theory. Besides I didnt make such a claim. I suggest you to read the papers that I posted.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören These papers are not written by mathematicians. Any theorem about the bootstrap contains "when $n \to \infty$", don't you agree ? If not, could you show me a link to a theorem not assuming $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you re right from the mathematical point of view. But the question is: if we want to prove something or if we want to make something work. I am following the second one. If we *have to* follow the first one, then we need to talk from the beginning.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Ok but **why** would it work ? With $n=3$ the bootstrap distribution is "highly discrete". In this situation one cannot expect to achieve a confidence level close to the nominal confidence level.

Comment: The reason is written in a very understandable way in those tutorial papers. It seems like magic but it works. There are also some theoretical justifications why it should work.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I'd like to see the result with the sample $50$, $51$, $52$. I don't believe it can work. Here are some related discussions https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-April/102828.html and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33300/determining-sample-size-necessary-for-bootstrap-method-proposed-method

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent your second post expains everything well. Small sample size calls bootstrap. However if it will work or how much work for very small sample size is another question. Then your claim that only for 3 samples seems correct.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Moreover the efficiency should depend on the parameter of interest. Here we want a confidence interval for the probability $\Pr(X \in [a,b])$ which involves both the mean and the standard deviation. I have already tried bootstrap intervals for variance components in some simple mixed models, and I swear they are really too short.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I see.. Okay. Thanks for the information.